# Prove two angles equal in billiard scenario.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In the diagram, $AB$ and $DC$ are perpendicular to $AC$.  Segments $BC$ and $DA$ are drawn and intersect at $E$.  Then $EF$ is drawn perpendicular to $AC$.  The problem is to prove that $\theta = \angle BFA$ = $\angle DFC=\phi.$

[image: Billiards Shot]

I was able to label all the distances and prove that $\tan \theta = \tan \phi,$ so that solved the problem.  My proof needs a coordinate system and knowledge of trig, but my audience doesn't really have those.  So I'd like a compass-n-straightedge-9th-grade-geometry solution.

If you're curious, this comes from my pool shark nephew.  Billiard balls are at $B$ and $D$ and the cushion is $AC.$  He wants to locate point $F$ where the two angles are equal.  His proposed method is to find the intersection of $BC$ and $DA$ (I suppose he can do this using his cue stick as a straightedge) and then eyeballing the perpendicular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $ABC\sim FEC$ we have $${AB\over EF} = {AC\over FC}$$ and since $ACD\sim AFE$ we have $${EF\over DC} = {AF\over AC}$$ So we have $${AB\over DC} ={AF\over FC}\implies AFB\sim CFD$$ and thus a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Reflect the image in the base and use similar triangles to show $BFD'$ is a straight line

$F$ is where $BD'$ intersects $AC$. This may be easier since $D'$ is not on the table

[image]

Comment: I've tried that but no success.

Comment: @Aqua  Yeah, I think he's assuming the conclusion.  The only way I can make similar triangles here is to assume that $BD'$ is a straight line.

Comment: $\triangle AFE$ and $\triangle AFE'$ are similar to $\triangle ACD$ and $\triangle ACD'$ so  $\triangle BFE$ is similar to $\triangle BD'C$ making $\angle BFE$ equal to $\angle BD'C$.  Combine this with $FE$ being parallel to $AB$ and $CD$ and $D'C$ and perpendicular to $AC$ and $AF$ leads to $F$ lying on $BD'$ and the angles being equal